# opencv CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED what does this feature do?

Tags: c++, opencv

I see in OpenCV it uses `#if CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED` in many places. for example

```
#if CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED
for( ; i <= width - 4; i += 4 )
{
    ST f = ky[0];
    const ST* S = (const ST*)src[0] + i, *S2;
    ST s0 = f*S[0] + _delta, s1 = f*S[1] + _delta,
        s2 = f*S[2] + _delta, s3 = f*S[3] + _delta;

    for( k = 1; k <= ksize2; k++ )
    {
        S = (const ST*)src[k] + i;
        S2 = (const ST*)src[-k] + i;
        f = ky[k];
        s0 += f*(S[0] + S2[0]);
        s1 += f*(S[1] + S2[1]);
        s2 += f*(S[2] + S2[2]);
        s3 += f*(S[3] + S2[3]);
    }

    D[i] = castOp(s0); D[i+1] = castOp(s1);
    D[i+2] = castOp(s2); D[i+3] = castOp(s3);
}
#endif
```

in `filter.cpp`

Does this feature have any other advantage than doing 4 float operations in a loop means less number of condition check? If yes then what is it. If no then when put it in a macro, why can't we use it always?

Comment: My guess is loop-unrolling, though I might be wrong.

Comment: @rwong You're right. See details from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [OpenCV's revisions](http://answers.opencv.org/answers/698/revisions/):

> **`CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED`** (?? default)default) - Experimental feature, that activates some 4- or 8- unroll loops. It theoretically helps compiler optimize the code, and improves memory access. However, the coverage of this feature in code is still very limited.

Comment: part of my question was if it helps then what are the possible reasons for keeping it under macro which can be disabled. Is there a scenario where it can hurt the speed of execution ? And please help me understand what does it mean when you say "coverage of this feature in code is limited" and if possible why ?